# How do I use MvvmCross with linked projects?

Tags: mvvmcross, portable-class-library

Is it possible to use MvvmCross with [Shared Projects](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/315c13a7-2787-4f57-bdf7-adae6ed54450), or a similar technique of sharing code between projects? If so, How?

It seems MvvmCross is built around using PCL. If I use PCL, how do I overcome the problem of not being able to reference platform-specific 3rd-party libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: This should work - just as linked files works. What problems have you hit using them? For PCL techniques see  the N=31 walkthrough - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n31-injection-platform-specific.html

Comment: @Stuart, so far I've only watched the N=0 video. In it, you add MvvmCross to the PCL project, and it adds this App class with initialization code. If I'm not using PCL, I won't have this App class, right? would MvvmCross still work? I'm trying to make a simple cross platform app for a presentation, nothing fancy.

Comment: BTW, looking at nuget, there are a number of MvvmCross packages, none of which is called "MvvmCross Hot Tuna Starter Pack". which one should I choose?

Comment: I also haven't seen a tutorial on how to use MvvmCross with linked files.

Comment: I created a Shared Project, and then created an Android Class Library, and added a reference to the Shared Project. When I added the MvvmCross nuget, it added stuff for a platform project, with a Setup.cs, and not for a core project, with App.cs. What should I do to create a core project with MvvmCross and shared projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add *App.cs* class to your shared project. The same way you need to add your view models and other code. All namespaces will be automatically resolved. [Look for solution explorer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh4Jc.png) In my case *AppInit.cs* inherits *Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxApplication*

Comment: I was afraid of that. Well, since I plan to use DI for the platform specific parts, I'll go with PCL rather than fight MvvmCross about this.

Comment: @TsahiAsher Just curious -- this sounds like a small one-time change when you set up a project.  Am I missing something?  Is there something you anticipate "fighting" with during the lifetime of a project, or are you just saying this one thing is too much of a consideration?  Just curious, because I'm thinking about trying out using mvvmcross with a shared project myself.

Comment: @BerntHabermeier you would normally add the mvvmcross nuget package to the shared code project. it works with PCL, i doubt if it will work with shared project, because the nuget package has a target project type defined for it. also, the excellent Ninja Coder for MvvmCross VS extension knows how to add ViewModels to a PCL project, I don't know if it works with a shared project.